# How do I disable logging messages on `autobahn`?

Tags: node.js, websocket, bitcoin, autobahn

I'm using `bitstamp-ws` to get trade data from the exchange. It uses `autobahn` under the hoods, which is logging messages on my console:

```
got event trade on 5:25:06 PM
```

How do I disable that behavior?

Comment: This is not something that the Autobahn library does. This has debug-logging, but the above is not a debug log message. Otherwise it does not log anything by itself.

Comment: This is not down to the Autobahn library. This has allows debug logging, but the above is not a debug log message.